# SQL Server triger and only update if exsist in another database

Tags: sql-server

I have a trigger that works just fine. However I found that if using the application GUI to update an item the trigger will not allow it to work in the GUI unless I create the item in multiple databases the trigger updates.

Basically I want the trigger to run, but either error out or stop if the same UID does not exist in the other 3 databases the trigger updates.

This is my current trigger.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgSecPIN] 
ON [dbo].[cat_validation]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE [eqcas02].[dbo].[cat_validation]
    SET secondarypin = I.secondarypin
    FROM [eqcas02].[dbo].[cat_validation]
    JOIN inserted I ON [eqcas02].[dbo].[cat_validation].[name] = I.name

    UPDATE [eqcas03].[dbo].[cat_validation]
    SET secondarypin = I.secondarypin
    FROM [eqcas03].[dbo].[cat_validation]
    JOIN inserted I ON [eqcas03].[dbo].[cat_validation].[name] = I.name

    UPDATE [eqcas04].[dbo].[cat_validation]
    SET secondarypin = I.secondarypin
    FROM [eqcas04].[dbo].[cat_validation]
    JOIN inserted I ON [eqcas04].[dbo].[cat_validation].[name] = I.name
```

Comment: check for `IF EXISTS` before your `UPDATE`s

Comment: So I am looking to add something like this before the UPDATE? IF EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM [eqcas02].[dbo].[cat_validation] WHERE [name]=[name]     or this completely incorrect?

Comment: I figured this out. I was missing ...   `SET NOCOUNT on`

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT on
```

Once I added the NOCOUNT everything has been working fine.